# Spring Integration to invoke multiple methods and response back to the same bean

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, spring-integration

I'm a newbie in Spring Integration. In the current scenario, I was trying to call methods like this:

```
MyObject.setMyList();
MyObject.setMyList1();
MyObject.setMyList2();
MyObject.setMyList3();
```

I had a interface to define the gateway, but my problem is how could i run this multiple methods at once using the spring integration and return `MyObject`. All the methods are interdependent here.

Second case: I had  a method which is dependent on the another method result. Method2 depends on Method1 result.

```
method2.getMethod2Result(method1_String).
```

How can I handle this situation using Spring Integration?

I know how can handle it Java, but not in Spring Integration.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `bean` in spring integration, you only have messages. Assuming your bean is actually the payload of some message, you could achieve both your use-cases by writing custom [transformers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html) (like [payload enrichers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#payload-enricher)) which return the same object after invoking some sequence of methods on it.

Comment: I need to get the same object using the spring integration.

Answer (score 1):

If your use-case is so tight, I don't see reason to decouple that using message channels and a bunch of service-activators.

Looks like it's just enough to write some custom POJO and refer to it from one `<service-activator>`.

That custom POJO should encapsulate method invocations on your `MyObject`.

From here your `MyObject` will be the same and can be an `inbound` as well as an `outbound` `payload`.

Read more Docs, please.

Answer (score 0):

For first case may be you can use Splitter-Aggregator pattern where you can call different methods for each path and combine the results at aggregator. For second case where result of one invocation goes to other, you can simply use

`<service-activator>`

with mutliple in and out channels